# Not getting any tweets using TwitterUtils and Spark Streaming

Tags: scala, twitter, apache-spark, spark-streaming

So, I've been trying to get a stream of tweets using TwitterUtils and Spark Streaming, in scala language. This is my code so far, I think it should be enough to achieve what I'm looking for, but it seems like it isn't getting any tweets. The output is like this:

Time: 1312300000

//Tweets should appear here

Time: 1312360000

---

```
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import java.io._
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

object TwitterPopularTags {

    def main(filtroLoc: Array[String]): Unit = {


    System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.consumerKey", CONSUMERKEY)
    System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.consumerSecret", CONSUMERSECRET)
    System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.accessToken", ACCESSTOKEN)
    System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.accessTokenSecret", ACCESSTOKENSECRET)

    val ssc = new StreamingContext("local[2]", "TwitterPopularTags", Seconds(60),System.getenv("SPARK_HOME"))
    val stream = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, None)
    stream.print


        ssc.start()
        ssc.awaitTermination()
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you seeing any exception? Or error message? Since you're not providing any authentication method.

Comment: No, there is no exception. What do you mean with not providing any authentication method? 

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem but then i used different consumerKey,consumerSecret ,accessToken ,accessTokenSecret and I was able to get the tweets.